# Python: is list() somehow inplace?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I observed an order dependency when using `list()` that I don't understand. I'm starting with a zip `mytup` and I've tested 3 versions of code with the following outcomes. `df_q` is a regular pandas DataFrame:

```
#ver1
df_q.loc[list(mytup)] # first access works fine
df_q.loc[list(mytup)] # TypeError: Cannot infer number of levels from empty list

#ver2
list(mytup)
df_q.loc[mytup] # TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
df_q.loc[mytup]

#ver3 works as excepted
mylist = list(mytup)
df_q.loc[mylist]
df_q.loc[mylist]
```

To me, since I'm getting an error only in the second call in `ver1`, I initially thought that `list()` somehow had some undocumented inplace behavior, but obviously it isn't as `ver2` doesnt work. `ver3` works as expected but I don't understand what's going on in 1/2.

Comment: `mytup` is a really misleading name for something that isn't a tuple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `zip` returns a zip object, which is an iterator. Most well-behaved iterators are single pass:

```
>>> z = zip((1,2),('a','b'))
>>> z
<zip object at 0x10193a908>
>>> next(z)
(1, 'a')
>>> next(z)
(2, 'b')
>>> next(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> list(z)
[]
```

In other words:

```
>>> z = zip((1,2),('a','b'))
>>> first = list(z)
>>> second = list(z)
>>> first
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
>>> second
[]
```

So, if you want to re-use the zipped values, you need to keep a reference around to the materialized list, just as you do in your third attempt.

Just to be clear, this isn't specific to the `list` function, but with anything that iterates over the zip-object:

```
>>> z = zip((1,2),('a','b'))
>>> d1 = dict(z)
>>> d2 = dict(z)
>>> d1
{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
>>> d2
{}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! Can you tell me what would be the appropriate way to reset the iterator if I wan't to e.g. list(z), dict(z) successively?

Comment: @JohnSmith `zip` iterators are single pass, most iterators are. You can't reset them. This makes them very memory efficient, so if you *need* to use them more than once, you'll have to some materialized data structure around. Or just re-create the zip-object. Note, I would probably just do something like `my_list = zip(x, y); my_dict = dict(my_list)`